# Count number of records written to Hive table in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have this code.

```py
val query = event_stream
    .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS .select(from_json($"value", schema_simple).as("data"))
    .select("data.*")
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("orc")
    .option("path", "hdfs:***********")
  //.option("path", "/tmp/orc")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs:**********/")
    .start()

println("###############" + query.isActive)
query.awaitTermination()
```

I want to count the number of records inserted into Hive.

What are the options available? And how to do it?

I found `SparkEventListener` `TaskEnd`. I'm not sure if it would work for a streaming source. I tried it, it's not working as of now.

One approach I thought was to make `hiveReader` and then count the number of records in the stream.